Windows Service Installer for c# console app using Topshelf
I have C# console application that I made Windows Service out of using Topshelf. I would like to make an installer now, I´ve seen some tutorials for how to make installer out of C# Windows service app, but I assume it is not usable for me as I have console app that uses Topshelf, so my question is what is the simplest way to make Windows Service installer out of console app that uses Topshelf framework.
Thank you.
I´ve tried WiX, and Microsoft Installer extension but with no success.

The following may be of interest: Topshelf Command-Line Reference
